# Not Finishing Activity in Android

Tags: android, activity-finish

I have a registration form in android wherein the user can enter data from it. The user can search for Clinic. After that searching, the user submitted the record, and logout. If the user doesn't have no business with that app, the user can exit BUT when the user pressed the Exit button, it does not exiting, instead it goes to the Searching activity all over again even if the user is logout already. Can someone help me figure out why I can't finish my activity?

Search Activity

```
btn_Close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegForm.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("from", "Search_Cancel");

            startActivity(myIntent);
            Search.this.finish();
        }
    });
```

Android Manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Search"
        android:noHistory="true" > 
    </activity>
```

Comment: You can start activity search all over again, try to start the `Activity` Search after you `finish()`

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758786/how-to-exit-current-activity-to-homescreen-without-using-home-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finish() will make your active Activity pop from the Back stack but your others Activities will remain on that so if you want to exit whole app you should use Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when you are starting your Last Activity to Clear your Back Stack

Comment: when you are starting your Activity with Intent add this Flag like : intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     } then start your Activity.

Comment: Should I need to use finish()?

Comment: yes if you want your Last Activity ends so you have to use finish,more information on : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 2):

Activities are finished with the `this.finishActivity(Activity.RESULT_OK);` call. 
**Note:** You may also specify other results located in the `Activity` class as static finals.